# Advice on minimal sorting algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

This is a little sorting algorithm I concieved the other day:

```
def my_sort(vals, reverse=False):
    copy = vals[:]
    f = max if reverse else min
    while copy:
        max_val = f(copy)
        yield max_val
        del copy[copy.index(max_val)]
```

The pseudo-code is something like follows:

1. Take input as a list `vals` and make a copy `copy`.
2. While `copy` has elements:

   a. Apply max or min to `copy` and get that value.

   b. Yield the value and remove the value from `copy`.

I have a couple questions related to this algorithm:

1. If this has already been concieved, what is the name of the algorithm?
2. What is the efficiency of this algorithm?
3. Are there any improvements that can be made to make this algorithm faster?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Sorting algorithms", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @Prune My search didn't yield anything that looked quite like `my_sort`, so I figured I'd ask about it here. Jesse Li provided a pretty nice answer.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far related to the 3 question? Share **YOUR** findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the efficiency of this algorithm?

Horrible.

- For every item in the list (an O(N) operation)
- ... take the max or min of the remaining list (an O(N) operation)
- ... and then remove the item from the original which requires list compaction (also an O(N) operation).

So it's an O(N^3) algorithm. Cubic complexity == very very bad.

> Are there any improvements that can be made to make this algorithm faster?

Delete it and use a proper sort algorithm. Sorting is a solved problem, unless you have some domain-specific data patterns you can exploit, so don't reinvent the wheel =)

- Bubblesort -> O(N^2)
- Insertion sort -> O(N^2)
- Quick sort -> O(N log N)
- Merge sort -> O(N log N)

For Python in particular use the built-in sort function; it's a good algorithm to start off with, and most likely it's backed by a native implementation which will be faster than doing the same algorithm in interpreted code.

Comment: Understood. I didn't think it would have a practical application.

Comment: Better yet, use the built-in sort.

Comment: Quicksort is in worst case onel **O(n²)**. Only In average it is O(n log n). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Taking the max/min and removing the item are both done once for each item, so you get O(n^2), not O(n^3).

Comment: @Thierry No they aren't; `min/max` is done once for the entire remaining list for each item that is removed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are talking about [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), or at least something very similar. Selection sort has `O(n^2)` complexity (although because this algorithm yields the next value instead of moving it to the front of the list, it takes `O(n^3)` time as explained by solidpixel's answer) , so not ideal. In terms of improvements, your best bet is probably to use a different algorithm - insertion sort is also `O(n^2)` but is more efficient on small lists, and on larger lists you should be using an `O(n log n)` sort.

Alternatively, if it's really important to you that you yield the first value immediately (e.g. it's a really big list and you need the first element of the sorted list a lot sooner than you do the entire list), instead of deleting the value you could overwrite it with the minimum value (and perhaps save the minimum value somewhere, so you don't need to recalculate it every time). This avoids the problem of list compacting, shaving off a factor of `N` in complexity.

Comment: I want to expand this exelent answer with a little explanation, why insertion sort is better than selection sort:
Using selection sort, you have iterate over an unsorted list region over and over again, picking the maximum which may be anywhere, like you do in your pseudo code. But when you iterate over a sorted region, you can use [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is much faster (O(log n)) than walking over the complete list region, because it uses a [Divide&Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) tactic.